# copy timestamp value from one table to other table in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, timestamp

I'm using `nodejs` to develop an application and I have to create a history table where I 'm basically just copying the old records from main table and inserting in history table when main table records get updated or deleted .
I have a field  `created_at` of type `timestamp without time zone` .When I select rows from main table using select query  I get `created_at`=`2018-03-15T09:14:06.980Z`,which in postgres DB is something like `2018-03-15 09:55:53.382` .This is the object I get after select query:

```
{
id: '8',
created_at: 2018-03-15T04:25:53.382Z,
user_id: '7',
updated_at: 2018-03-15T06:27:50.762Z }
```

But when I try to insert the the record the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields become values like `Thu Mar 15 2018 09:55:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
 which creates error
Now I'm confused and also can't understand how to convert this format of timestamp `Thu Mar 15 2018 09:55:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
 to timestamp without timezone

Also this problem doesn't get solved if I convert it to milliseconds!

Answer (score 0):

converting the fields `created_at` and `updated_at` to ISO String using `date.toISOString()` or using `new Date(Date.parse(date)).toJSON()` does the magic